# Retry f = opener.open(url) on error

Tags: python

I have a python script that makes 2 calls in order, however, sometimes I get the error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

I would like to have it retry the call every time it does not get a 200 response.

How would I do that?

Comment: `while not success: send request` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use try and except clauses:

```
while True:
   try:
       ... # make your conncetion here
       break
   except:
      print "soemthing went wrong, retrying"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of object your "opener" is, but I guess you want something like

```
import urllib2

def open(url):
    while True:
        try:
            u= urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            if e.getcode()==200: #no idea if it's even possible for a HTTPError to have code 200, but this way we're prepared for anything.
                raise
        except Exception:
            pass
        else:
            if u.getcode()==200:
                return u #on success, return
        #fallthrough: code!=200 or Exception has been raised, so try again.
```